# Having trouble resizing an actionlink button in mvc

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I can't seem to change this actionlink using custom CSS. When I use bootstrap it works fine. But I need to add a lot of customs to it. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

HTML

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {                            
    <div id="yasin03" class="card">

        <div class="pull-right btnDelete">
            @Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#x1F5D1;"), "Delete", new { id = item.BulletinId})
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">@Html.Raw(@item.BulletinCategoryEnum)</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@item.BulletinDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")</h6>
            <p class="card-text">@Html.Raw(@item.BulletinBody)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

CSS:

```
.btnDelete {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong either, mostly because I don't know what's wrong :). Right now your code would appear to have a `div` that's 40 pixels wide, which wraps a link. What else do you need? Also, it would be helpful if you provided the HTML that is rendered by that code. Finally, note that IDs must be unique to the document: since you have an id in a `foreach`, it is not unique.

Comment: Yeah so I want that link to be 40px wide but it's not being affected by the CSS. My CSS isn't applying to the link. Ill add an image right now

Answer (score 1):

It's not being affected by the css because your only setting the width of the div that is wrapping your button. To get your link to be 40px give it a width of 100% so it fills the div. You could also give the link a unique id, or a class might be easier inside the foreach, and set its width to 40px.

Answer (score 0):

The button doesnt really disapear, but this will help you in your task to archive your goal, also check https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp i hope thats what your looking for otherwise i didnt understand the question

```css
.btnDelete {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    color: orangered;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.btnDelete:hover {
background-color: white;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-right btnDelete">Button</div>
```